# how to calculate the cells gap in a grid like Sudoku game?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, game-development, starling-framework

this is what i'm using now and it's working

```
var cellSize:Number = 36;
var cellGap:Number = 4;
var row:Number;
var col:Number;

for (var a:int = 0 ; a < puzzleSTR.length ; a++)
{
        col = a % 9;
        row = Math.floor(a / 9);

    var cell:Cell = new Cell(puzzleSTR.charAt(a));
    cell.x = col * (cellSize + cellGap);
    cell.y = row * (cellSize + cellGap);                
    container.addChild(cell);
    cells.push(cell);
}
```

this result in 9*9 grid with 4 pixels gap between them, now i want the same result but the gap should be 8 every 3 cells horizontally and vertically, exactly like a sudoku.

i use actionscript3 but i only need the concept in any language
thank you

Comment: Hint: you can detect if a number is a multiple of 3 when `number % 3 == 0` (remember that you need to test `number + 1` instead of `number` when indexes start from zero)

Comment: The number of extra pixels is `Math.floor(col / 3) * 4` for  `x`. Same for `row` / `y`.

Comment: I'll encourage you to take a look at my above comment again, if you haven't already. It's *way* more readable to do it this way.

Comment: Chris G is right, not only it is more readable, but it will also work for grids with number of rows or cols > 9 whereas the accepted solution won't

Comment: yes i actually used this thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're positioning the elements absolutely, you'll need an extra 4px gap (in addition to the default 4px gap, equalling 8px), from the fourh col and *for every subsequent col* in that row. From col 7 an onwards, you'll need to add 8px, to account for both gaps.

The same logic applies to row spacing. Note that I'm comparing with `3` and `6` to get the fourth and seventh col, as the variables are zero-based.

```
var extraColPadding = col >= 6 ? 8 : col >= 3 ? 4 : 0;
var extraRowPadding = row >= 6 ? 8 : row >= 3 ? 4 : 0;

cell.x = col * (cellSize + cellGap) + extraColPadding;
cell.y = row * (cellSize + cellGap) + extraRowPadding;
```

Comment: for anyone seeing this in the future in david's reply extraColPadding should be outside the brackets like this (cellSize + cellGap) + extraColPadding; otherwise the gap will be doubled every 3 columns.

Comment: ah yes, `extraColPadding` wasn't intended to be included in the multiplication. Updated.